# Updating a document in mongodb

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack

For school I am making a project in Angular with specific goals, we haven't had a lot of lessons, so I am still a beginner. My project is almost done, but I stumbled across updating my document in the MongoDB database. 
My project is some kind of community site that you can compare to Reddit. So it is also possible to upvote a post made by a user.

Now the thing is that I can not upvote my post. I get the error:

```
this._spell.toJSON is not a function.
```

For the updating I am using a PUT call, but I have never seen this in class so I searched it on the internet and try to implement it. My backend call with Insomnia works and my Post is getting upvoted. But when I try to call the API in my frontend, I get this error.

I have read through multiple websites and through Stackoverflow, but still have not find a solution for my problem.

**My Code**

The post.component code receiving the event:

```
upvote() {
  this.post.upvote();
  this._dndDataService.upvote(this.post.id, this.post).subscribe();
}
```

The Post.Model having the from and toJson

```
toJSON() {
  return {
    title: this._title,
      originalPoster: this._originalPoster,
      category: this._category,
    comments: this._comments.map(i => i.toJSON()), //fixen indien null
    spell: this._spell.toJSON(),
    dateCreated: this._dateCreated,
    votes: this._votes
  }
}

static fromJSON(json: any): Post {
  const post = new Post(
    json.title,
    json.originalPoster,
    json.category,
    json.spell,
    json.dateCreated
  );
  post._id = json._id;
  post._votes = json.votes;
  post._comments = json.comments.map(Comment.fromJSON); //fixen indien null
  return post;
}
```

My dndDataService calling my backend, this is almost the same like the POST method to create posts. I also use the `map((p:any) : Post => Post.fromJSON(p))` and here I don't get the Error mentioned above.

```
upvote(id: string, post: Post): Observable<Post> {
  const theUrl = `${this._appUrl}/post/${id}/vote`;
  return this.http.put(theUrl, post)
    .pipe(map((p:any) : Post => Post.fromJSON(p)));
}
```

Now comes my backend call receiving the whole post and updating my database, I am using a router.param function to get the post with the correct ID, this works as I use it for multiple purposes:

```
router.put('/API/post/:id/vote', function (req, res) {
  Post.update({
    $set: {
      votes: req.post}
    },
    function (err, post) {
      if(err)
        res.send("Error updating post");
      res.json(post);
    })    
});
```

I even sent my teacher for help on updating this code, but it still does not work. I really hope some of you can help me.

If you need my whole code, please say what you need and I will update my post.

Also possible to find my code on: https://github.com/SFieuws/WebsiteDnd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this with not sending the whole post to my backend but just the votes. Secondly getting my post from the id is wrong because with that I called my old amount of votes, stupid mistake.

**Data service**

```
upvoteComment(id: string, points: Number): Observable<Comment> {
  const theUrl = `${this._appUrl}/comments/${id}/vote`;
  return this.http.patch(theUrl, {points})
    .pipe(map((c:any) : Comment => Comment.fromJSON(c)));
}
```

**Backend Patch Call**

```
router.patch('/API/post/:post/vote', auth, function (req, res) {
  let query =  Post.findById(req.params.post).populate("comments").populate("spell");
  query.exec(function(err, post){
    if(err) res.send("Post not found");
    post.votes = req.body.votes;
    post.save(function(err, result){
      if(err) res.send("Error updating post"); 
      res.send(post);
    })
  });
});
```